# Functions and graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Consider a finite set $X$ of order $n$ and a symmetric function $f: X \times X \rightarrow X$.

$f$ can  straightforwardly be considered as a [multidigraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) with

- $n$ "object" nodes, representing the elements of $X$, and
- $n(n+1)/2$ "argument" nodes, representing the pairs of arguments
  of $f$.

Each of the $n$ object nodes has $n+1$ out-arrows to its corresponding argument nodes. Each of the $n(n+1)/2$ argument nodes has exactly 2 in-arrows from its correspoding object nodes and 1 out-arrow to its corresponding "function value" node (an object node).

Now invert the situation and consider an arbitrary multidigraph with $N = n + n(n+1)/2 = n(n+3)/2$ nodes with the property **P**, that $n$ of them (the *object* nodes) have $n+1$ out-arrows and another $n(n+1)/2$ of them (the *argument* nodes) have exactly 2 in-arrows and 1 out-arrow.

> **Question**: Can - or rather: under which conditions can - be shown that a
>   multidigraph with property **P** is
>   **bipartite**, in the sense of:
>
> - the out-arrows of an *object* node go to an *argument* node and vice
>     versa
> - the in-arrows of an *object* node come from an *argument* node and vice
>     versa.

Comment: Your point is that you want to have unlabelled digraphs, right? So the object node x has two parallel arcs to the argument node (x,x)?  I think you need to require n such parallel arcs with different targets, otherwise it seems to me that bipartness does not suffice to make the graph be a functional graph.  (An example, forgetting about the functional values: consider n=3, and the disjoint union of a K_{2,4} and a digraph on three nodes, one of which has outdegree 4, the other 2 having each indegree 2)

Answer (score 1):

It's not true even for $n=1$. Consider the graph with two nodes, $a$ and $b$, with edges as follows:

- $a\to a$
- $a\to b$
- $b\to b$

Thus, $a$ has exactly two out-arrows, $b$ has exactly two in-arrows and exactly one 
out-arrow. So it has property $P$ for $n=1$ but is not bipartite in th sense you wanted, since both $a$ and $b$ point at themselves.

(Note that the arrow $b\to b$ contributed both to the in-arrow sum and the out-arrow sum at $b$, which may not be how you wanted to consider things.)